# Break a line when consecutive points fall within different groups in the grouping factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a plot where the points on the graph do not connect when consecutive points falls in different groups within the grouping factor, and that the line should break and not continue when such a scenario occurs.

Here is an example of data and code I used, which do not give me exactly what I want though.

```
species <- c(rep(c("P1","P2","P3","P4","P5","P6","P7","P8"),each=3))
disease <- rep(c("dis1","dis2","dis3"),4)
score <- c(1,1.7,4,2,5,1,3,4,6,2.5,4,8,2,2,6.2,3,6,4,4,6,1,2,7,4.5)
plantdata <- data.frame(species,disease,score)

#add column for grouping factor
plantdata$valid <- ifelse(plantdata$score <=4, "valid","invalid")
plantdata$status <- paste(plantdata$species,plantdata$valid, sep="_")

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(plantdata, aes(x = disease, y = species)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size=score)) + geom_line(aes(group =status))
```

From the code, I get the plot below.

[image]

From the plot above, the lines joining the points in the levels of a group cross each other, for example, see plant P7. Since the point on (dis1, P7) and (dis2,P7) fall in different categories, I don't want a line between them even though (dis3, P7) is in the same group as (dis1,P7). Therefore, for the case of P7 there should be no line joining the points along P7, since the progressive points of (dis1, dis2,dis3) fall in different groups within the grouping factor.

And also, the lines should be drawn only connecting consecutive points with a "valid" attribute to it within the grouping factor. For example, along the P8 points, there should also be no line joining (dis2,P8) and(dis3, P8), since I don't want lines joining points with an "invalid" attribute to it.

An update of the same data with 6 diseases instead is here

```
> dput(plantdata)
structure(list(species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "P6", "P7", "P8"), class = "factor"), disease = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), class = "factor", .Label = c("dis1", "dis2", "dis3", "dis4", "dis5", "dis6")), score = c(1, 1.7, 4, 2, 5, 1, 3, 4, 6, 2.5, 4, 8, 2, 2, 6.2, 3, 6, 4, 4, 6, 1, 2, 7, 4.5, 1, 1.7, 4, 2, 5, 1, 3, 4, 6, 2.5, 4, 8, 2, 2, 6.2, 3, 6, 4, 4, 6, 1, 2, 7, 4.5)), .Names = c("species", "disease", "score"), row.names = c(NA, -48L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `grepl` to find `status` with `_valid` and then apply `diff` to see if status is the same between `disease`. Finally, when plotting pass `NA` if status is different

```
library(data.table)
setDT(plantdata)
# Make sure that data is sorted by species and disease
setkey(plantdata, species, disease)
# Is status between disease same (`SAME == 0`)
plantdata[, SAME := c(0, diff(grepl("_valid", status))), species]

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(plantdata, aes(species, disease)) + 
    geom_point(aes(size = score)) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = ifelse(SAME == -1, NA, disease))) +
    coord_flip()
```

**Edit:** I switched `disease` to y-axis in order to skip `NA` values when plotting (applying `coord_flip` to show them on x-axis).

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @PoGibas, this is exactly what I was looking for. I have tried to use the same code for a dataset with 6 diseases, but it tends to bring about the line crossing, am I missing something in the grepl() or diff() functions? Thanks.

Comment: @Nuru I updated my answer, can you please check if this is expected result?

Comment: this is the result i was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Nuru How can I improve my answer so you would accept it?